# Form validation regular expressions using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation

Hello How can i add regular expressions in to my form validation i have done really basic form validation below and would just like to add regular expressions to increae security any ideas?? Noob at js

```
    <head>
    <script>
    function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
    if (x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
    var x = document.forms["login"]["password"].value;
    if (x == "") {
    alert("Password must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
```

Comment: If your concern is security you should defiantly do your validation on the server side.

Comment: no not really i just want to test the above using regular expressions for the two field username and pass word... any ideas?

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial for regex [JS Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Comment: can u include it in my code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
    if (!/^\w+$/.test(x)) {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
    var x = document.forms["login"]["password"].value;
    if (!/^\w+$/.test(x)) {
    alert("Password must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you please explain line 3 i understand you have a regex but what is .test reffering to

Comment: Just a method in RegExp, if match the result will return true, otherwise return false

Comment: And I think you should read  JS Regex Tutorial in Dieter's comment

Answer (score 0):

Kerwin'answer is to test whether the input is empty. 'test' function will test the input string with a pattern to see if there is a match. /^w+$/ is the regex pattern you want to test against, it means:

- the string starts with (by ^)
- one or more than one alphanumeric and underscore characters (by \w+, \w means a character from character set [a-zA-Z0-9_], and +
  means one or more than one)
- then the string ends(by $, this ensure the user input ends with the character from above set, not sth like space or new line)